# Do subsidies affect current routes?

Tags: openttd

When local authorities offer subsidies for a route between two destinations, any new routes are obviously subsidized. However, I cannot tell if existing routes (say, a bus route from one town to another) are subsidized when a new subsidy is offered. Do I need to create a new route, new stations and a new route, or will my current routes be enough to get the subsidy?

Answer (score 3):

A subsidy is awarded to the first company to move any quantity of the relevant goods from the source town/industry to the destination town/industry (ensure stations have the source/destination inside their catchment area!). Once awarded, all deliveries of that goods from source to destination made by that company will receive the subsidy bonus, this is *regardless of the route, station or type of transport*.

That is to say the subsidy effectively is awarded to the company, not any specific route.

*Note that this rule changed in version 1.0.0 <sup>1</sup> and differs from older versions, which bound the subsidy to a specific pair of stations.*

---

So, if a new subsidy happens to have a source and destination that coincide with an existing route, and that route triggers the subsidy award before another company does, then **yes, the subsidy will be applied to that existing route**.

<sub>1. See http://wiki.openttd.org/Subsidy</sub>

Comment: That does seem to coincide with some of the results I'm getting. I have seem some subsidies awarded to existing routes, but not to others. It would definitely help if there was a clear explanation of when a station has a town within its catchment area (industries are much more obvious in that regard) for the purposes of a subsidy.

Comment: @Tyler K. easiest thing to do is to try to place a station on top of your current station then you can see the catchment radius, either that or enable disjoint stations